# How to find the intersection and union of 2 indexed arrays with associative arrays as their children?

Tags: php, arrays

The scenario is this. I have an array of items, in this format:

```
$a = [
    ['name' => 'John'],
    ['name' => 'Doe']
];
```

In a further update, I get a new array with some values removed while some added. It looks like this:

```
$b = [
    ['name' => 'John'],
    ['name' => 'Smith']
];
```

How would I calculate the union and the difference of these 2, so that I can remove `Doe` from my database and add `Smith` since my new data has these changes?

Comment: Might be this can help http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: Or rather... [`array_uintersect`](http://php.net/array_uintersect) and [`array_udiff`](http://php.net/array_udiff).

Comment: Thanks! Please could you give me an example. I am not able to apply it to my situation.